# Using EXTRA_OUTPUT for an ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intent crashes the Camara App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

### Code

```
String dirPath = File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + context.getPackageName() + File.separator + "mediaDir" + File.separator;

// Path where I want the recorded video to be placed.
File videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + dirPath + "videoName.mp4"); 

Uri videoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(videoFile); 
intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoFileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE_CODE);
```

---

### LogCat output

```
A/StagefrightRecorder(11209): frameworks/base/media/libmediaplayerservice/StagefrightRecorder.cpp:636 mOutputFd >= 0**
...
<A very long memory dump>
...
W/Camera(18796): ICamera died
...
E/Camera(18796): Error 100
```

---

This bug occours in `HTC Nexus One` phone, while not in newer devices like `Nexus 7`. It seems to be [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1480), in which several device makers like HTC, Motorola, etc re-implemented the camara app re-introducing this bug that fixed using the `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Is there a way to get this working properly in devices like the `Nexus One`? (apart from not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` and then copying the file when received `onActivityResult` to the desired destination)

Note:
I've already tried several things like making sure the destination file exists, using `createNewFile` and `mkdirs`.

**Update:**
Updated the code to show where the file is to be placed.

Comment: Where, specifically, are you trying to have the file be written?

Comment: Good point. I want to place it on the corresponding folder for the application on the SD Card. Doing this with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Just updated the question to show this.

Comment: Die you all camera.unlock?

Answer (score 1):

Never use string concatenation to build file paths. Use the proper `File` constructor, please.

Beyond that, there are thousands of camera apps on the Play Store, let alone on devices. The user can choose any of them to handle your request. While ideally all would honor `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, nobody is holding a gun to those app developers' heads to force them to do so. Hence, using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` should be considered a "best efforts" approach, useful for casual circumstances only, where if the third-party app misbehaves, that's not a problem.